# Visual Studio 2012 overwriting non compiled files (.js and .cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

When building my solution visual studio overwrites the contents of any file that I've changed that isn't a .cs file. It is an MVC 4 project. Any help would be great thanks.

Edit : The files are edited within visual studio.

If I change a file's content from "some html" to "new better html" when I compile the file will be reverted back to "some html"

Comment: What sort of things does it place into these files?

Comment: Overwrites it where? No files should be written to upon compile (generally, that is) - it's _reading_ what there is to compile!

Comment: Overwrites it with what? Are these files you edited externally or within Visual Studio?

Comment: it rewrites what ever the previous value of the file was. I just deleted a file and on build the file was completely restored. It's almost like VS is caching files.

Comment: Post your solution and project files and tell us what files are being overwritten?

Comment: If this happens it would indicate that the code your modifying isn't user generated code but machine generated code.  One has to ask why are you modifying files generated by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

The only conceivable way this could happen is a pre or post build event exists that's copying those files from somewhere else and it's happenstance that the version you're working with matches where they are being copied from.

Comment: As far as i can tell there are no pre or post build events at all. It only happens when I build the solution not the individual projects. It is also not happening for anyone else using the same code. Could it be a VS setting?

Comment: @AaronF., I can't conceivably think of another way. One of those projects must be checked out and have an event running. Like you said, it only happens when the solution is built, so unfortunately that's all I can see. If it's not happening for anybody else it may be a modification that was made for testing, not checked in, and then subsequently never removed because you just moved on.